# Laravel mongodb find documents inside the array

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I am using jenssegers/laravel-mongodb query builder.

How to get data inside the array an match?

```
{
  "_id": "59720531a3e92e190c006e46",
  "course_lists": [
    [
      {
        "id": "CS653R",
        "url": "1500713710618"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "id": "IE162D",
        "url": "1500713787536"
      },
      {
        "id": "CE515R",
        "url": "1500713787536"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

How do I find where the field "course_lists.id" whether match my variable course_name?

ps. course_name  variable is "CS653R"

Comment: `db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind:{path: '$course_list'}},{$match: {"course_list.id": "shurelous"}}])`

Comment: Oh, you have an array inside another array... I strongly recommend you to change your object structure, otherwise you'll have to use complex queries for simple tasks like this

Comment: Thanks you for comment. I just changed the structure ^^